# Odata Linq Expand, How I can select the columns I need

Tags: c#, linq, odata

```
var query = (from a in Orders.Expand("Order_Details")
select a).Take(9)
```

This statement generates all columns, just need some columns

Answer (score 1):

Select the results into a new anonymous object:

```
var query = (from a in Orders.Expand("Order_Details")
select new { a.Column1, a.Column2, etc... } ).Take(9)
```

Or if you need it to be strongly typed:

```
public class OrderDetails {
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
}

var query = (from a in Orders.Expand("Order_Details")
select new OrderDetails { OrderID = a.order_id, CustomerID = a.customer_id } ).Take(9)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using an Entity Data Model (edmx file) in a WCF Data Service. (because you are using the "Expand" function.)

If this is the case....
You can create a complex data type (via the edmx Model Browser) then add all the needed column types to this complex data type.

You then create a custom function in your data service that passes back data of this complex type.

Your client app can use the complex type defined in the service because of the service reference allowing you to recognize that complex type.